# palindrome int in java

Tags: java, palindrome

I tried to use some codes on Stack Overflow but when I used some codes,I didn't get the answer I want, this is my code now:

```
public class JavaApplication7 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean answer = rev(1221);
    if(answer == true) System.out.println("true");
    else System.out.println("false");

}
static boolean rev(int number){
    int reverse = 0, remain;
    int num = number;
    while(number > 0){
        remain = number % 10;
        reverse = (reverse * 10) + remain;
        num = num / 10;

    }
    return number == reverse;
  }  
}
```

I want to check if palindrome is equal to the orginal int.

Comment: This condition `number > 0`  in `while(number > 0)` is either always true or always false because `number` does not change.

Comment: @c0der I guess no answer at all counts as not the answer OP wanted. `remain = number % 10;` also means `remain` is a nice constant `1` (since `number` doesn't change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two bugs relating to confusing `num` (the local copy which you're modifying) and `number` (the parameter which you don't modify). I would make it `final` to make clear that the value is constant. And then use `num` consistently. I would also simplify the code a little. Like,

```
static boolean rev(final int number) {
    int reverse = 0;
    int num = number;
    while (num > 0) {
        reverse *= 10;
        reverse += num % 10;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return number == reverse;
}
```

And similarly in `main`, using an `if` to print `true` or `false` is pointless (and if you're going to do that use `if (answer)` - don't add unnecessary `== true`). But, I would prefer,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean answer = rev(1221);
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Which outputs

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rev function should be as below.

```
    reversedInteger = 0, remainder, originalInteger;

    originalInteger = num;

     while( num != 0 )
            {
                remainder = num % 10;
                reversedInteger = reversedInteger * 10 + remainder;
                num  /= 10;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static boolean rev(int number){
    int reverse = 0;
    int num = number;

    while(number > 0){
        reverse = reverse * 10 + number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return reverse == num;
}
```